# How to allocate memory for array of structs?

Tags: c++, c, struct, malloc, wrapper

I've a C++ library (really a wrapper for another C++ library) and I need pass some `struct`s to my C application.

I don't know how allocate the memory dynamically.

I get a segmentation fault.

**library.h**

```
struct my_substruct {
    unsigned char                   id                    ;
    time_t                          date                  ;
    char                            *info                 ;
};
typedef struct my_substruct         My_substruct          ;

struct my_struct {
    char                            *description          ;
    unsigned char                   value                 ;
    My_substruct                    *substruct            ;
};
typedef my_struct                   My_struct             ;
```

**library.cpp**

```
unsigned char getStructs(My_struct *structs)
{
    vector <structCPPLibrary> structsCPPLibrary = getFromCPPLibrary();
    unsigned char numStructs                    = structsCPPLibrary.size();
    structs                                     = (My_struct *)malloc(numStructs*sizeof(My_struct));
    unsigned char indexStruct                   = 0;
    for (auto s : structsCPPLibrary)
    {
        structs[indexStruct].description        = (char *)malloc(s.description.size() + 1);
        strcpy(structs[indexStruct].description, s.description.c_str()); // In 's' is a std::string
        structs[indexStruct].value              = s.value;               // In 's' is an unsigned char too
        unsigned char numSubstructs             = s.substructs.size();   // In 's' is a vector of Substructs
        structs[indexStruct].substruct          = (My_substruct *)malloc(numSubstructs*sizeof(My_substruct));
        unsigned char indexSubstruct            = 0;
        for (auto sub : s.substruct) {
            structs[indexStruct].substruct[indexSubstruct].id   = sub.id;    // In 'sub' is an unsigned char too
            structs[indexStruct].substruct[indexSubstruct].date = sub.date;  // In 'sub' is a time_t too
            structs[indexStruct].substruct[indexSubstruct].info = (char *)malloc(sub.info.size() + 1);
            strcpy(structs[indexStruct].substruct[indexSubstruct].info, sub.info.c_str()); // In 'sub' is a std::string
            indexSubstruct++;
        }
        indexStruct++;
    }
    return indexStruct;
}
```

**main.c**

```
void getStructFromWrapper(void)
{
    My_struct *structs;
    unsigned char numStruct = getStructs(structs);
    show_content(structs);
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're using C. I'd remove the C++ tag, since the answers for that would be entirely different.

Comment: @aschepler: It looks like a mixture: The OP uses the range-for and `vector` which is not in C.

Comment: Unrelated: if what's returned by `getFromCPPLibrary` has suitable lifespan, you might be able to use `vector <structCPPLibrary> & structsCPPLibrary` and `auto & s` and save yourself a lot of allocating and copying.

Comment: `getStructs(structs);` - variables in C are passed by value, not by reference. The changes of `struct` will be nor visible outside the function. Also to compile with C++ you usually have to have cpp extension.  `uct}.su` - you have some strange errors, mostly types, unrelated to the problem. Please fix them. Your allocation I think maybe looks ok, but you don't check for any allocation errors.

Comment: @user4581301 Are you talking about opaque type for use as a handle? if you could tell mevwith some detail about that I'll appreciate it

Comment: No. About pointers. You pass the pointer by value. `struct = malloc()` is not visible outside the function.

Comment: @KamilCuk you're right with cpp extension, I'm going to edit my question to change it. In relation with variables in C, with your last edit, I understood

Comment: `you can pass a pointer to return some data` - yes, but a valid pointer to a valid location and then you modify the memory where the pointer points to. You pass an uninitialized pointer. And then you modify the pointer value. Imagine that: `int main() { My_struct *structs = 0; getStructs(structs); printf("%p\n", struct); }` with `void getStructs(My_struct *structs) { structs = malloc(blabla); }`. It will print `0`. Because the variable structs is never modified. In your code you pass uninitialized pointer to `show_content(structs);`. Please use debugger to debug the code and pinpoint the error

Comment: If outside the function I don't know the size, how I can allocating memory?

Comment: Or if this is C++ you can pass a reference to the pointer `getStructs(My_struct *&structs)` if this is C you can pass a pointer to the pointer. Anyway, it is unclear what you want to do. Please invest time into good C book and refresh your knowledge about pointers and functions.

Comment: You will get not segmentation fault but compile error for `structs[indexStruct}.substruct`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
unsigned char getStructs(My_struct *structs) {
    ...
}
getStructs(structs);
```

To

```
unsigned char getStructs(My_struct **p_structs) {
    // C function can't be pass by reference, so convert to a reference here
    auto& struct = *p_structs;  
    ...
}
...
getStructs(&structs);
```

Your problem is that your `struct = ...` line is not modifying the value of `structs` in `getStructFromWrapper`.

Comment: thanks @eric but the populating ```p_structs```  into ```unsigned char getStructs(My_struct **p_structs)``` will be the same like I do before? I would appreciate it if you completed your example by adding values to ```**p_structs``` to clarify me

Comment: _"[...] will be the same like I do before"_ - yes, I'm using `...` here to mean "exactly as you had it before"

Comment: Ok. I'd a bug when print a variable to checking and the execution was fail. Thanks

Comment: something goes wrong with this allocating memory. Sometimes inside the loop ```for (auto sub : s.substruct)``` I'm getting a memory access error. With valgring I get ```Invalid read of size 4
==14990==    at 0x48E93E8: getStructs Address 0x9ac9f54 is 4 bytes inside a block of size 44 free'd``` and ```Invalid write of size 1
==14990==    at 0x48E93FC: getStructs Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd```

Comment: I'd recommend asking a new question with a minimal example that reproduces the issue